# R language and Benford's law: warning in program implementation

Tags: r, benford.analysis

Can anyone help me? My code has some warnings. How can I solve these problems?
Input is a simple vector 1*196608 that is extracted from Matlab.

warnings:

```
1: In empirical.distribution$dist.freq - benford.dist.freq :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

2: In ((empirical.distribution$dist.freq - benford.dist.freq)^2)/benford.dist.freq :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

3: In empirical.distribution$dist - benford.dist :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

4: In as.data.table.list(x, keep.rownames = keep.rownames,  ... :
  Item 1 has 9 rows but longest item has 10; recycled with remainder
```

My code:

```
library(benford.analysis)
library(R.matlab)
f=readMat('vectorimage.mat')
s=f$vectorimage
y=as.numeric(s);#convert to numeric type
d=benford(y,number.of.digits = 1)
print(d)
plot(d)
```

Comment: output figure: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zLYnI.png

Comment: do you intent to connect R with matlab in this code?

Comment: No. I only used MATLAB to generate data. Suppose this data a simple data

Comment: The code is not reproducible, can you give some update, of what your data looks like? can be like head(y) or str(y)

Comment: Ok. please see my form data in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6dE.png

Comment: I think that because the number " 1" has exceeded a threshold, R has added a bar at the end of figure ( i.stack.imgur.com/zLYnI.png)

Comment: tick accept my answer please if it helps you, have a great day :)

Comment: sorry bro, fortunately the change didn't work. number.of.digits must be 1.

Comment: yes you can accustomized that based with your own data

Answer (score 1):

Based by your data, I think you have negative and positive values both varying in y, which is likely normally distributed, therefore you can modify benford, like this:

```
benford(y, number.of.digits = 3, sign = "both", discrete=TRUE, round=3)
```